# get Dockerfile for Google App Engine python 3

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am developing a python web server in Google App Engine.

I want to debug it in VScode so I want to get the Dockerfile for the latest python 3 version in the gcr.io/google-appengine/python

Where do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime/tree/master/runtime-image) of the Python Runtime for App Engine Flex, in that repository you can find the Dockerfile and all the Scripts to create an Docker container similar than the used on App Engine Flex

```
# The Google App Engine base image is debian (jessie) with ca-certificates
# installed.
# Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/debian-docker
FROM ${OS_BASE_IMAGE}

ADD resources /resources
ADD scripts /scripts

# Install Python, pip, and C dev libraries necessary to compile the most popular
# Python libraries.
RUN /scripts/install-apt-packages.sh

# Setup locale. This prevents Python 3 IO encoding issues.
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
# Make stdout/stderr unbuffered. This prevents delay between output and cloud
# logging collection.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/python-interpreters/latest/interpreter-3.4.tar.gz && \
    wget https://storage.googleapis.com/python-interpreters/latest/interpreter-3.5.tar.gz && \
    wget https://storage.googleapis.com/python-interpreters/latest/interpreter-3.6.tar.gz && \
    wget https://storage.googleapis.com/python-interpreters/latest/interpreter-3.7.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf interpreter-3.4.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf interpreter-3.5.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf interpreter-3.6.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf interpreter-3.7.tar.gz && \
    rm interpreter-*.tar.gz

# Add Google-built interpreters to the path
ENV PATH /opt/python3.7/bin:/opt/python3.6/bin:/opt/python3.5/bin:/opt/python3.4/bin:$PATH
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 50 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/pip3 pip3 /opt/python3.7/bin/pip3.7 50

# Upgrade pip (debian package version tends to run a few version behind) and
# install virtualenv system-wide.
RUN /usr/bin/pip install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements.txt && \
    /opt/python3.4/bin/pip3.4 install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements.txt && \
    rm -f /opt/python3.4/bin/pip /opt/python3.4/bin/pip3 && \
    /opt/python3.5/bin/pip3.5 install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements.txt && \
    rm -f /opt/python3.5/bin/pip /opt/python3.5/bin/pip3 && \
    /opt/python3.6/bin/pip3.6 install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements.txt && \
    rm -f /opt/python3.6/bin/pip /opt/python3.6/bin/pip3 && \
    /opt/python3.7/bin/pip3.7 install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements.txt && \
    rm -f /opt/python3.7/bin/pip /opt/python3.7/bin/pip3 && \
    /usr/bin/pip install --upgrade -r /resources/requirements-virtualenv.txt

# Setup the app working directory
RUN ln -s /home/vmagent/app /app
WORKDIR /app

# Port 8080 is the port used by Google App Engine for serving HTTP traffic.
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080

# The user's Dockerfile must specify an entrypoint with ENTRYPOINT or CMD.
CMD []
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Dockerfile you can use:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "server:app"]
```

You can also look at the [Github Repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime#kubernetes-engine--other-docker-hosts)